# What does the error "Failed resolution of: Lorg/tensorflow/lite/gpu/GpuDelegateFactory$Options" mean?

Tags: java, android, gpu, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run a TensorflowLite object detection app with custom model on emulator (Pixel_2_API_30) in Android Studio. Earlier I tried to run the app on real device (Redmi Note 5) and everything worked fine. When I launch on virtual device firstly I see the background of my MainActivity and then everything disappears. I don't get any errors. In order to find the error log I had to detele filters. Here is the error:

```
2022-09-17 15:30:45.849 8131-8131/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 8131
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/tensorflow/lite/gpu/GpuDelegateFactory$Options;
        at org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate.<init>(GpuDelegate.java:52)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV4Classifier.create(YoloV4Classifier.java:106)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.MainActivity.initBox(MainActivity.java:556)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegateFactory$Options" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~RuidL0T-Xrm76Ba2iYwkEg==/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-j7P9_Ul8AM0EKw12bQCN8g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~RuidL0T-Xrm76Ba2iYwkEg==/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-j7P9_Ul8AM0EKw12bQCN8g==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~RuidL0T-Xrm76Ba2iYwkEg==/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection-j7P9_Ul8AM0EKw12bQCN8g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate.<init>(GpuDelegate.java:52) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.YoloV4Classifier.create(YoloV4Classifier.java:106) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.MainActivity.initBox(MainActivity.java:556) 
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection">

    <uses-sdk />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/tfe_od_app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ObjectDetection">
        <activity
            android:name=".CalculationActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".AllValuesActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".AllValuesActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetectorActivity"
            android:label="@string/tfe_od_app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    //buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                //includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }

//        ndk {
//            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}



// import DownloadModels task
project.ext.ASSET_DIR = projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/assets'
project.ext.TMP_DIR = project.buildDir.toString() + '/downloads'

// Download default models; if you wish to use your own models then
// place them in the "assets" directory and comment out this line.
//apply from: "download_model.gradle"

apply from: 'download_model.gradle'

dependencies {

    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.5.0'
    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-gpu-experimental'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.0-alpha03'
    annotationProcessor  'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha03'

    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta01'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    //implementation 'com.savvi.datepicker:rangepicker:1.2.0'
}
```

Could somebody please help me to find how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Proguard removed that class during compilation. Can you try setting `minifyEnabled=false` in your gradle, and see if the problem guess away?

If it does, you'll need to add some Proguard rules to keep that class intact

Comment: The app still closes but I got a different error:  `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 11407
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: Following operations are not supported by GPU delegate`

Comment: looking at your gradle file, it looks like you aren't providing a valid version for any of the `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite` implementations. Try using the actual latest version, which I believe is 2.6.0

Comment: I tried with tensorflow 2.6.0 but got same error: `Can not open OpenCL library on this device - dlopen failed: library "libOpenCL.so" not found
    Falling back to OpenGL
    TfLiteGpuDelegate Init: OpenGL ES 3.1 or above is required to use OpenGL inference.
    TfLite`

Comment: Well, that's a different error -- it's finally running properly, and it's telling you that your device's GPU doesn't support that feature

Comment: Do you know if any emulators in Android Studio do support this feature?

Comment: You didn't say that you were trying to do this inside the emulator. I have no idea if that's even possible, but if it is, it would probably depend on whether your GPU supports OpenCL, and if it's capable of virtualizing it and passing it through to the emulator. I would suggest that you test it on a real device instead

Comment: @ALiCeP. it's unrelated to this question but try to google for <uses-native-library />