# Age Gender Estimation on Android from camera frame

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite, estimation

I followed the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCuCNtsYz6k&t=1376s) and got this error:

```
E/skurt.genderag: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.esrabaskurt.genderage, PID: 11140
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/tensorflow/lite/gpu/GpuDelegateFactory$Options;
        at org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate.<init>(GpuDelegate.java:52)
        at com.esrabaskurt.genderage.age_gender_recognition.<init>(age_gender_recognition.java:56)
        at com.esrabaskurt.genderage.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:79)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegateFactory$Options" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.esrabaskurt.genderage-z09vSMzWFjnjuhOeZ8M92A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.esrabaskurt.genderage-z09vSMzWFjnjuhOeZ8M92A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.esrabaskurt.genderage-z09vSMzWFjnjuhOeZ8M92A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate.<init>(GpuDelegate.java:52) 
        at com.esrabaskurt.genderage.age_gender_recognition.<init>(age_gender_recognition.java:56) 
        at com.esrabaskurt.genderage.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:79) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11140 SIG: 9
```

Here is age_gender_recognition.java:

```
    import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;
    public class age_gender_recognition {
...
    private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate=null;
    ...
    age_gender_recognition(AssetManager assetManager, Context context,String modelPath,int inputSize) throws IOException
    {
...
   **gpuDelegate =new GpuDelegate() (age_gender_recognition.java:56);**
...
       }}
```

and (CameraActivity.java:79):

```
age_gender_recognition =new age_gender_recognition(getAssets(),CameraActivity.this,"model.tflite",inputSize);
```

"build.gradle" file is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.4.3'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.4.3'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.4.3'

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.4.3'
...
}
```

It gives error about `GpuDelegate()`. Any suggestion?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756592/what-does-the-error-failed-resolution-of-lorg-tensorflow-lite-gpu-gpudelegatef

Comment: can you show more of age_gender_recognition.java file, since the code snipped that you provided is not enough